# glmnet installation Error: C++17 standard requested but CXX17 is not defined

Tags: r, installation

I am trying to install `glmnet` on an HPC by running `install.package("glmnet")`. However, right after downloading, I get the following error:
`Error: C++17 standard requested but CXX17 is not defined`.

I found a similar error message [here](https://travis-ci.community/t/error-in-shlib-internal-args-c-17-standard-requested-but-cxx17-is-not-defined/6748) and suspect that I have to do similar edits to my `Makevars` file. However, I was not sure what exact edits I should make, because `glmnet` also has Fortran components, instead of "just" C++, like the package which is linked in the post above.

Any help on how I might be able to install the package is much appreciated!

Cheers!